# How to define the treatment effect of triple diff (DDD)

Tags: econometrics

I am examining the triple diff (diff-in-diff-in-diff)(DDD) in a staggered setting.

Normally, when it comes to DDD, I understood that we examine the differential movement between two sub groups based on a standard (or generalized) DiD.
For example, in a generalized DiD, we can examine the impact of anti-corruption laws on salary of labors. Where anticorruption laws are staggered implemented around the world.

Afterwards, from my understanding, if we want to examine the difference between the impact of this law on salary of male worker and female worker, we need to perform DDD.
At that time, the general equation change from

$Y = ai + bt + cD + epsilon$

$i$ standing for each worker and $t$ standing for each time period.

where D equal to 1 for all observation after the year a country passed the law

to

$Y = ai + bt + c*D*g + epsilon$

where $g$ is the group for gender of worker
**So, I am wondering if g=1 for make worker and 0 for female worker or "." for female worker?**

**And I am wondering whether it is a right thinking ?**